# Passing ajax variables to Canvas

Tags: javascript, ajax, canvas

I'm trying to animate some variables I get trough ajax. The update of the variables itself work fine. I need to pass these variables to a Javascript Canvas Gauge. I found this code online [Javascript Canvas Gauge](https://github.com/tomnomnom/tacho/blob/master/index.html). There's a HTML slider at the bottom. I want to replace that with one of my ajax variables.

I think I have to make changes here

```
 var demoInput = document.getElementById('demoInput');
 demoInput.oninput = function(e){
        console.log(this.value);
        demo.setAttribute('data-val', this.value);};`
```

I tried to replace the `var demoInput` with my ajax variable but I think there's a mouse event necessary to perfom an update of the gauge. I'm pretty new to Javascript maybe someone here can give me a hint. Thanks!

Comment: The demoInput is a DOM object, which is a Javascript reference to the HTML input you have selected. When your Ajax call returns, you want to update the value of this input object, not replace the reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Nice tacho sample! For your purpose

First remove `demoInput` as you want by removing this html code from sample

```
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="range" id="demoInput" min="0" max="100" value="0">
    </div>
```

Second update js code like this

```
    var demo;
    window.onload = function(){
        demo = document.getElementById('demo');
        tacho(demo, {
            "title": "Widgets Per Second", 
            "max": 110,
            "markInterval": 2,
            "bigMarkInterval": 10,
            "redLinePoint": 0.85,
            "autoScale": false
        });
    };
```

Note that here I put demo outside to become global variable for easy reuse. I also remove

```
    var demoInput = document.getElementById('demoInput');
    demoInput.oninput = function(e){
        console.log(this.value);
        demo.setAttribute('data-val', this.value);
    };
```

Because you want to replace `demoInput` by your ajax variable

Finally update canvas by your ajax variable, because You don't specify your ajax function and variable. I just give a simple example

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
          url: "/test.php",
          success: function( your_ajax_variable ) {
            demo.setAttribute('data-val', your_ajax_variable);  // Update canvas by your ajax variable here
          }
        });
    </script>
```

In your code, I think you can call `demo.setAttribute('data-val', your_ajax_variable)` in your ajax function to update canvas